# Traveling magnetic field

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, phase, induction, linear

I'd like to do some experiments with a traveling magnetic field. To start with, I'd like to create a traveling magnetic field with a set of coils and try to propel an aluminum sheet. A basic model of a Linear Induction Motor.
Like this experiment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAfFgyWvB4 (t=10:10).

I am wondering to what kind of power supply these coils are connected? 3-phase AC?

Comment: Yes, Laithwaite used 3-phase AC for these demos.

Comment: Zwaan, in order for someone can help you, could you describe more precisely, and  using words, what do you want to, instead of just posting a link to a 18min vintage video?

Comment: 3 phase good. 2 phase maybe. Rate of motion of field needs to be slow enough for plate to be able to follow. At say 50 Hz plate may simply vibrate and heat deoending on mass and friction etc.

Comment: Did you ever do anything with this set up?